# MarketingCloudSDK - Push notifications channels

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Let say that my application has 2 types of news, type1, and type2. Also my application has 2 switches so that user can select which news type he would like to receive, or essentially which notificaiton type.
The question is, is it possible to have some kind of notification types in MarketingCloudSDK, so that if user subscribed to type1, but not to type2, he never receives type2 push notification?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Marketing Cloud Mobile Push SDKs (Android and iOS) then yes.  You can use "Tags" (http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/tags.html) to segment your audience by user preference.  When creating your messages in the Marketing Cloud you would add an inclusion filter for the given tag(s).